# How Can I Store and serve an image in Django Rest Framework using Mongoengine (Mongodb module for Django)

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

here is my models.py :

```
models.py

class Resource(Document):
    instruction = fields.StringField(required=True)
    picture = fields.ImageField(required=False)
```

and my serializer :

```
class ResourceSerializer(serializers.DocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Resource
        fields = '__all__'
```

and my views.py

```
class ResourceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = ResourceSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Resource.objects()
```

and this is the response that i get when im trying to list the pictures

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
       "id": "5ac4886a91a48946801813c9",
       "instruction": "test",
       "picture": "5ac4886991a48946801813bf"
    }
]
```

> note : mongodb using gridfs to storing the imagefiles

in case that mongodb using gridfs to storing the imagefiles , how can i send the images to client ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to send back the image url?
If my assumption is correct you can try with [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

It should look like this:

```
class ResourceSerializer(serializers.DocumentSerializer):
    picture = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Resource
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_picture(self, obj):
        return obj.picture.url
```